# ffmpeg library libfdk-aac.so.1 absence ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ffmpeg

Good morning, I had install ffmpeg by web site: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu. I removed all install problems. But i had problem when launch ffmpeg command "ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libfdk-aac.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I had look at in web and i found the problem is the "libfdk-aac0" library is not present.
This library (was present on ubuntu 20.04 and I installed it) is not present on ubuntu 22.04.
What i have to do?

Thanks

Comment: Seems odd, perhaps reinstall the library: `sudo apt-get install libfdk-aac-dev` and try ffmpeg again...

Comment: It's not available for Ubuntu 22.04 yet - If it's not available anywhere, then I guess that the only solution is to build it from sources, and install.

Comment: @funder7 This one: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libfdk-aac-dev

Comment: Thanks I also try this solution.

Comment: @attilio-olivieri you should signal that the answer helped you by clicking the "v"==accept icon that is beside the answer of funder7. It will also show others that the answer has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the package has not been released on 22.* apt repository, but you can find the debian package here: https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libfdk-aac2/download. Be sure to download the right architecture one.

Comment: thanks, I test it. If I didn't get your answer I would have tried the ubuntu version 20.04 library. But I don't know if it would have worked.

Comment: it works, thanks.

Comment: Probably it would work as well, consider that my link points to debian, I think that ubuntu 20.04 is closer to version 22. Anyway if you face any problem, you can build from sources. Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be available directly in apt now (running Kubuntu 22.04), so you don't need to download the debfile separately. However, for me (at least) the issue remained. I had to manually softlink the library which fixed problems with VLC and ffmpegthumbnailer.

I have the package installed:

```
sudo apt install libfdk-aac-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libfdk-aac-dev is already the newest version (2.0.2-1).
```

and the libraries exist:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfdk-aac.
libfdk-aac.a
libfdk-aac.so        
libfdk-aac.so.2      
libfdk-aac.so.2.0.2
```

Installing the debfile manually doesn't create this file either. I've tried making a soft link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfdk-aac.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfdk-aac.so.1
```

Though this might not work all the time, because in theory so.1 and so.2 are not ABI compatible (as I understand the naming schemes). But why would these tools (also installed on apt) depend on an outdated library. So it's possible something else went wrong during the upgrade.